# Como diminuir o espaço entre as imagens do carousel bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Boa noite galera, gostaria de saber como posso diminuir esse espaço branco entre as imagens do carousel. Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

meu código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/0054A6/fff/&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/002d5a/fff/&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/d6d6d6/333&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>          
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/002040/eeeeee&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/0054A6/fff/&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/002d5a/fff/&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/40a1ff/002040&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
    </div>
     </div>
    <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

    <div class="container">

        <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image"
                    width="140" height="140">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p class="text-justify">Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula
                    ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image"
                    width="140" height="140">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p class="text-justify">Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis
                    consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum
                    nibh.
                </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img class="rounded-circle" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Generic placeholder image"
                    width="140" height="140">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p class="text-justify">Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta
                    felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
                    massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->


        <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent
                    commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" src="https://occ-0-337-2219.1.nflxso.net/art/54244/272bd909045456af974c61068f168cafc3a54244.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent
                    commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
                <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" src="https://occ-0-337-2219.1.nflxso.net/art/54244/272bd909045456af974c61068f168cafc3a54244.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent
                    commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" src="https://occ-0-337-2219.1.nflxso.net/art/54244/272bd909045456af974c61068f168cafc3a54244.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->


        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <footer>
            <p class="float-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
            <p>&copy; 2017 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc diz esse espaço à direita?

Comment: Sim, gostaria que aparecesse todos os slides ao mesmo tempo

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Rafitos!

Tentei montar as estrutura do código pra você, utilizei o carrossel do próprio framework.

Bom, para que ele funcione como você quer, precisamos setar algumas classes, vou usar o exemplo do seu código:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500/0054A6/fff/&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
 </div>
```

A classe carousel-item exibe os itens do carrossel, no seu exemplo você está exibindo um item por vez, como você quer exibir vários itens, então nessa mesma div, você irá inserir os itens, por exemplo:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <div> item 1 </div>
    <div> item 2 </div>
    <div> item 3 </div>
</div>
```

E assim também para os demais que não contém a classe active :

```
<div class="carousel-item ">
    <div> item 4 </div>
    <div> item 5 </div>
    <div> item 6 </div>
</div>
```

Essa é a estrutura que deverá inserir, agora basta colocar as classes para que funcionem corretamente:

```
<div class="carousel-item row no-gutters active">
</div>
```

Você precisa setar a classe row e a no-gutters para remover os espaços, caso desejar deixar com espaço entre as imagens, basta remover.

E para cada item do slide, o código ficará assim:

```
<div class="col-3 float-left">    
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x450&text=1" alt="1">
 </div>
```

Você seta a coluna do tamanho que deseja e o float-left para setar a imagem a esquerda.

Tentei explicar tudo antes de só colocar o código para melhor entendimento, segue o código completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  
   <!-- o slide fica na mesma linha porque setamos o ROW
      e o NO-GUTTERS para remover qualquer espaço ao lado
     -->
    <div class="carousel-item row no-gutters active">
    
     <!-- Itens do slide
         para adicionar mais slides, 
            copie a div e troque a imagem 
         -->
     <div class="col-3 float-left">    
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x450&text=1" alt="1">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-3 float-left">    
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x450&text=2" alt="2">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-3 float-left">    
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x450&text=3" alt="3">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-3 float-left">    
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x450&text=4" alt="4">
        </div>
 
    </div><!-- FIM itens ativos -->
    
    
    <div class="carousel-item row no-gutters">
        <!-- Para adicionar mais slides, 
            lembre-se de inserir após a classe carousel-item 
        -->
      <div class="col-3 float-left">    
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x450&text=5" alt="5">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-3 float-left">    
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x450&text=6" alt="6">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-3 float-left">    
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x450&text=7" alt="7">
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-3 float-left">    
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/900x450&text=8" alt="8">
      </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <!-- controladores maior e menor -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```